# Save array value into a variable ether as String or Intval

Tags: php, yii

Wrongly I have Inserted adwords_id as ***String and Int*** into Database for Serprate Customers

```
  "adwords_id": "8409585555",
 "adwords_id": NumberLong(8409585597),
```

So When Am Updating It update **Only for Int adwords_id** when am giving ***condition*** as

```
$param['adwords_id'] = intval($adwords_id);
```

and when am giving ***condition*** as `$param['adwords_id'] = $adwords_id;`
It update Only for **string adwords_id**

So i need to Update my data base for both int and string with one ***condition*** then how could i change

```
$param['adwords_id'] = ?;


Note : not able to change in the database it is in the live ...there is huge data
```

for example

```
<?php  
$var_name1="678" or $var_name1 = 678;  

if (is_numeric($var_name1))  
{  
echo "YEs" ;  
}  
else  
{  
echo "no" ;  
}
```

?>
for both $var_name1="678" or $var_name1 = 678;   `output is YES`
**so can anyone help me other solution**

Comment: why don't you just change column type?

Answer (score 0):

The `is_numeric()` function is behaving as expected, testing both `"678"` and `678` should result on `true`.

I think that you might be looking for [is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

```
<?php
if ( is_int($param) ) {
    echo "int value";
} else {
    echo "string value";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your database table with phpmyadmin or whatever you are using and change the type of the column to integer or string whatever you want to use!

Comment: Sorry Not able to do static the database come from live ..there are so many